# Anyway to put Webbrowser control popups inside a new webbrowser instance

Tags: c#, popup, webbrowser-control

They reason i want to do this is so that I can actually have some control over the popup because there is a certain button that I'd like to click.

Thanks

Edit: using windows forms, here is the code for the webbrowser control

```
WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();
        w.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        w.Location = new Point(0, 34);
        w.MinimumSize = new Size(20, 20);
        w.Name = "Webbrowser";
        w.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        w.Size = new Size(616, 447);
        w.TabIndex = 1;
        f.Controls.Add(w);

        w.NewWindow += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(w_NewWindow);
        w.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(w_DocumentCompleted);
        w.Navigate(url);
```

The URL I broswers to has a popup which I don't want to close, but rather put into a new webbrowser control as opposed to IE if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to clarify this question more. I am guessing you are talking about ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question...

Take a look at the NewWindow2 event. In particular, you want to set the ppDisp parameter to a "new InternetExplorer" object.

Comment: What if NewWindow2 event is not firing?

Answer (score 1):

Look into Modial Windows.  That works for only IE.  However you can do the same with JavaScript and [JQuery Ui Core](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) has a nice on.